# How do I write to an activex control in Word from Lotusscript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I would like to use a Word document as a template to fill in with Notes data. I have the Word file created with five activex text boxes.Does anyone have an example of how to access those textboxes using Lotusscript?

MJ

Answer (score 0):

This was not easy to find out,  but here it is.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim doc As NotesDocument

'get Current NotesDoc
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
Set doc =uidoc.Document

'get WordDocument
Dim wApp As Variant 
Dim worddoc As Variant
Dim oTB As Variant
Set wApp=CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible= True
Set worddoc= wApp.Documents.Add()
wApp.Visible = True
Call worddoc.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ("Forms.TextBox.1")

'if you don't have the name off the TextBox1 let the system show you this with
'Msgbox ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Name ,0, "title"

worddoc.TextBox1.Value ="Hello" 'or doc.field1(0)

End Sub
```

The difference to your example is that I create the worddoc and the text box.
In your case you have to first get the file

```
Set wApps = CreateObject("word.application")
set worddoc = wApps.Documents.Open "C:\path-to-file\file.doc"
```

And then set all text boxes value

```
worddoc.TextBox1.Value ="Hello" 'or doc.field1(0)
worddoc.TextBox2.Value ="Hello" 'or doc.field1(0)
worddoc.TextBox3.Value ="Hello" 'or doc.field1(0)
```